# How to find and replace line(s) in multiple files using Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, find, find-and-replace

I have been messing with notepad++ for a bit now and am confused as to how to go about doing this:

I have a line in multiple files (Within a root directory) that I am searching for. Example:

```
Brittany (File 1)
     CookiesEaten 2
Tiffany (File 2)
     CookiesEaten 4
Bonqueesh (File 3)
     CookiesEaten 3456
.
.
.
```

My goal is to replace all of the `CookiesEaten` lines with a constant (I.E. `CookiesEaten 7`) but when I search and replace in multiple files, it does not remove complete line, which results in:

```
Brittany (File 1)
     CookiesEaten 7 2
Tiffany (File 2)
     CookiesEaten 7 4
Bonqueesh (File 3)
     CookiesEaten 7 3456
```

When in reality I want:

```
Brittany (File 1)
     CookiesEaten 7
Tiffany (File 2)
     CookiesEaten 7
Bonqueesh (File 3)
     CookiesEaten 7
```

**So how do I go on about finding a string, removing everything within that line, and replacing it with another string?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Using Notepad++ to find a string on a line in a file, and replace that entire line with the match with another string

> ### **Instructions**
>
> Open [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and press
> <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`F`</kbd> and then from the <kbd>`Find in Files`</kbd> tab options.
>
> **Now you'll...**
>
> 1. Put the string in the regex format of the **Find What:**
>    `^.*(CookiesEaten).*$`
>
> - The string will go between the "`()`" parenthesis just as shown above in `#1`
>
> 2. Put the 5 spaces and then the **Replace with:** `CookiesEaten 7` string
> 3. Put the **Filters:** as `*.*` or `*.txt` or whatever you are replacing file type wise
> 4. Put the **Directory:** where you want it to be (***the root folder***)
> 5. Check the `Regular expression` option
> 6. Select **<kbd>`Replace in Files`</kbd>**
>    [image]

> 7. It will prompt you if you want to replace all instances
>    [image]
> 8. Check the file(s) and all should be correct now

Comment: sorry about that. I didn't even see it at first. Thank you!